# Access to another page in same directory yields CORS error with file: URL

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to build a tiny browser-based app which will run from a file: URL without using a server.  (So I can just drop the files on a flash drive, and launch it by just double-clicking the HTML file.)  The app needs to read another file, but each approach I attempt to use yields a CORS error.

My two approaches have been:

- Make an AJAX request
- Load the content into an iframe and try to read the document

which yield the following errors, respectively:

- Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///PATHHERE' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
- SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Per [MDN's definition of an origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy):

```
Two URLs have the same origin if the protocol, port (if specified), and host are the same for both.
```

Based on that definition, any file: URL should be same-origin and hence CORS (being *cross* origin) would not apply.

I found that MDN has a [an additional page about file: URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Misc_top_level/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs) which states that the desired file must be in the same or subdirectory of the page's file to be considered same-origin.  I found that is true for Firefox, but Opera, Chrome, and Safari appear to not follow that idea but rather treat all file: URLs as cross-origin, even if the page is trying to load a copy of itself!

So I could just only use Firefox, except the catch is the file I'm trying to load is a directory and Firefox treats directory listings as cross-origin even if it is a subdirectory of the directory where the original page lives.  The error is "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///myapp/subdir. (Reason: CORS request not http)."  (Although I would content that it is not cross-origin, therefore shouldn't have to be HTTP.)

So is there any way in any current major browser (preferably Chrome since it would be available everywhere I'd want to use this) to get a directory listing over a file: URL?

And if not, is there any good reason why that's not supported, at least for directories under the folder where the page was loaded from?  As in, is there some security reason for it that just isn't obvious to me?  Or is it just the general bias against file: URLs?  (i.e. that any real app would be hosted on a webserver.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a security feature of internet browsers. Reading a file with file:/// protocol is **a big security problem**. That is why it is not allowed.

If you still want to read local file in your html page, you can use **electron.js** - it uses a different approach.

https://electronjs.org/